# How to get multiple shipping address in checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-address

I need to get multiple shipping address from quote, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$shippingMethods = array();
$addresses = $quote->getAllShippingAddresses();
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $id = $address->getId();
}
```